# sonarqube upgrade from 4.5.5 to 5.6

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Do we need to upgrade our Sonarqube 4.5.5 to latest LTS 4.5.7 before upgrading to 5.6? Or is it ok to upgrade directly to 5.6  as long as you are on the latest LTS branch 4.5.x?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to upgrade to 4.5.7.

Comment: I tried upgrading, but Webinterface said DB migration failed after about 4 hours (!), with the following error :

Comment: 2016.09.09 19:17:12 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB Migration or container restart failed. Process ended with an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to load plugin C [c]  We have version 1.7 of the C plugin. I cannot find it in the Sonar plugin library?      Then I tried to remove the plugin and got other errors, finally removeed all plugins just to get started, but got a new error :

Comment: 2016.09.12 13:47:58 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.server.platform.ws.SystemWs
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69) ~[sonar-core-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]

Comment: please use third-party apps like gist.github.com to copy/paste logs. The error relates to a bad installation. You should unzip SonarQube in a fresh directory, not in the previous installation directory.